# How i can print the file creation date of various files in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the file date creation of various files.

So I've tried use this code:

```
import os
import datetime

pth = r"my_path"

def listDir(dir):
    fileNames = os.listdir(dir)
    for fileName in fileNames:
        t = os.path.getctime(pth + str(\fileName));
        print('Nombre: ' + fileName + t)

listDir(pth)
```

But, that don't works. Another problem that i have is that i don't know how to put only in the date the `"Y/M/D"` characters.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you state the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem here.

While using `.getctime` the string you are passing is not a proper file-path. You are concatenating `pth` with `\filename`. This syntactically worng.

You are missing the `\` or other delimiter used in different `os` for specifying directories.

You can try the below answer -

```
import os
import datetime

pth = r"my_path"

def listDir(dir):
    fileNames = os.listdir(dir)
    for fileName in fileNames:
        file_path = os.path.join(pth, fileName)

        ts = os.path.getctime(file_path)        # this returns the creation timestamp.
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)    # this converts the timestamp to datetime object.

        print('Nombre: {0} --> {1}'.format(fileName ,dt.date()))    # dt.date() will return only the date from the datetime object.


listDir(pth)
```

Notes:

1. Use `os.path.join` for concatenating the paths as it takes care of which OS you are using. We don't have to worry about `/` or `\\` or any other delimiter.
2. Convert the date into `datetime` object as manipulating and `dealing` with datetime object will be much more easier than dealing with `strings`.